# Error al iniciar mysql con el puerto 3008

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

He reinstalado xammpp cuando configuro el archivo my.ini en config de mysql me da error al intentar entrar al  phpmyadmin os adjunto captura de dicho error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado a configurar el phpmyadmin de apache en config, donde esta localhost ponerle el 3008 pero tampoco ha funcionado
que puedo hacer?
gracias

Comment: Has reiniciado el servidor de MySQL y el del web con el que controlas el phpmysdmin? (Apache/nginx...)

Answer (score 0):

Ya tienes el puerto cambiado en el archivo `my.ini`.

Te falta cambiar el puerto en el archivo `php.ini`.

**1º paso**

Ir al archivo php.ini
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**2º paso**

Cambiar los parametros:

```
mysqli.default_port=3306
mysql.default_port=3306
```

Aquí le cambias el puerto `3306` por el `3008`.

Reiniciar apache y MySQL.